# AngularJS: Detect if current page is reloaded using ui-router1.x transitions events

Tags: angularjs

**AngularJS: Detect if current page is reloaded using ui-router1.x transitions
Which event is used to detect the page reload in ui-router1.x using transitions?**

Comment: Check https://html.developreference.com/article/13055843/Detect+F5+browser+refresh+from+angular-ui-router if it can help

Comment: This is a broken link

Answer (score -1):

I believe the event you are looking for is `$stateChangeStart`. For default router, you'd have to attach to `$locationChangeStart`.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
   if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: Already tried with "$stateChangeStart" event but it works only when the route gets changed, it's not working in case same page gets reloaded.

Comment: Question asks about same page being loaded